# SQL SERVER Convert URL/Link to Varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Good Day!

I have problem in regards with converting link/url to varchar.

`SET strSQL = strSQL + StrSQL = 'http://ph.nothing.com/crypt=' + ...`

I got an error in "/" and I don't know why. I already tried convert/cast to convert varchar/char/... on the link, however no luck.

Does anyone knows how to convert link to varchar?

Thank you and God Speed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use + instead of =

```
SET strSQL = strSQL + StrSQL + 'http://ph.nothing.com/crypt=' + ...
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! well I never thought that was easy :)